# Regex to remove all <br /> tags from beginning and end of a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I have a string with multiple br tags in beginning and end and in between also. But I want to remove all br tags which are in start of string or end of string.

```
Input : <br /> <br /> <br /> 
        <br /> <br />This is <br /> Test <br /> string. <br /> <br /> <br /> 

Output should be - This is <br /> Test <br /> string.
```

I tried following regex tp replace string

```
Input.replace(/^(<br( \/)?>)*|(<br( \/)?>)*$/, '')
```

But it is not working.

I have tried a separate regex to remove all br at end it is working.

```
Input.replace(/(<br \/>\s*)+$/, '')
```

How can I get similar regex to remove br tags from beginning also. Or If I can write a combined regex.

Comment: replace (<br \/>\s)+

Answer (score 8):

You can use following regex:

```
/^(\s*<br( \/)?>)*|(<br( \/)?>\s*)*$/gm
```

see demo https://regex101.com/r/cH7kL2/1

Note that since you have a multi-line string you need to use `m` flag which forced your regex engine to match the anchors at the start of each line.

Demo:

```
Input.replace(/^(\s+<br( \/)?>)*|(<br( \/)?>\s)*$/gm, '')
```

Comment: There are only two matches in the match information in your link

Comment: @TusharGupta So what's wrong with that? the result would be what OP wants.

Comment: Its replacing all br tag at the end but not replacing br tags at the beginning

Comment: @TBAG Do you tried the regex with the string in your question? it works fine in the link.

Comment: I tried with <br />
<br />
test Question<br />
<br />
<br />

Comment: I know it is matching here but somehow in real time scenario its not working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
Input.replace(/^( |<br \/>)*(.*?)( |<br \/>)*$/,"$2");
```

here the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WBfxm/68/

Comment: My br tags are as <br /> so I tried Input.replace(/(^<br \/>|<br \/>$)/g,"") but it is not working

Answer (score 2):

In case you need trim (white) spaces with br (pay attention browser handle different br format like `<br>, <br/>, <br /> and <br / >` use that: `/^(\s*<br\s*\/?\s*>\s*)*|(\s*<br\s*\/?\s*>\s*)*\s*$/g`. 
see example here https://regex101.com/r/ls9eoq/2

Comment: This is by far the best solution. Not elegant, but for a regex novice like myself, it does the job. The only solution I tested here that works across all browser.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a regex like this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('<br>Hello<br>world<br>','^(<br>)*(.*?)(<br>)*$','\\2');
```

**Sample**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('<br>Hello<br>world<br>','^(<br>)*(.*?)(<br>)*$','\\2');
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| REGEXP_REPLACE('<br>Hello<br>world<br>','^(<br>)*(.*?)(<br>)*$','\\2') |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Hello<br>world                                                         |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('Hello<br>world<br>','^(<br>)*(.*?)(<br>)*$','\\2');
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| REGEXP_REPLACE('Hello<br>world<br>','^(<br>)*(.*?)(<br>)*$','\\2') |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Hello<br>world                                                     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('<br>Hello<br>world','^(<br>)*(.*?)(<br>)*$','\\2');
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| REGEXP_REPLACE('<br>Hello<br>world','^(<br>)*(.*?)(<br>)*$','\\2') |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Hello<br>world                                                     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('Hello<br>world','^(<br>)*(.*?)(<br>)*$','\\2');
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| REGEXP_REPLACE('Hello<br>world','^(<br>)*(.*?)(<br>)*$','\\2') |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Hello<br>world                                                 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Input.replace(/^[(<br( \/)> )|(<br( \/)>)]*|[( <br( \/)>)|(<br( \/)>)]*$/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
Input.replace(/^(\ ?<br( \/)?>\ ?)+|(\ ?<br( \/)?>\ ?)+$/, '');
```

The modified code should clear all spaces and `<br>` or `<br />` tags infront or at the end of the string

here is working example: http://www.rubular.com/r/rHYW4DqJKT (Modified)

Edit: actually what you are missing is to give the replaced value to the original variable like so:

```
Input = Input.replace(/^(\ ?<br( \/)?>\ ?)+|(\ ?<br( \/)?>\ ?)+$/, '');
```

[Working example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryam877j/)

Comment: Not working. My test string is "<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
test Question"

Comment: replace doesn't replace the string itself, rather then it return the modified string

Answer (score 0):

**This one worked for me**

```
this.htmlToPreview = payload.parsedHTML.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/gm, '');
```

Answer (score -1):

**This will replace each occurrence within the inputValue**

```js
const regexBr = new RegExp('<br/>', 'gi');
const outputValue = inputValue.replace(regexBr, ' ');
```